# VSCODE : Disable HTML Auto Closing Tags only for Javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCODE to program my web apps using JQuery and when I want to work with divs and for example when I want to make a new div in JQuery, I write :

```
$('<div>
```

But VSCODE close instantly this html tag like this:

```
$('<div></div>
```

What i'd like is to keep this html closing tag in other languages, but disabling it on .js files. Is it possible using VSCODE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the extension "Auto Close Tag" this will do the Job:

```
    {
    "auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
        "html",
        "xml"

    ]
}
```

Put this in your VSCODE settings.json

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks